# Default type of a Ad?

Tags: google-ads-api

Currently doing a migration from old legacy code where we have a custom SOAP client to make calls to the AdWords apis. In the legacy code, we never specified a "Ad type". I'm wondering what the default for this is? Ad types are of several enumerations like "Product Ad", "Shopping Ad", etc

Another thing is the purpose of a "Product Ad". Is the Product Ad just a umbrella term meaning, "use all types"? I checked the implementation and it's a empty class extending the base template Ad class.

Thanks,
Regards,
Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adwords has lots of different ad formats, some are textual like "Expanded Text Ads", others are graphic, e.g. "Image Ads" or "Video Ads".

Here's a [list](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722124) of all supported creative types. These correspond (not always in an obvious way) to the different subtypes of the [SOAP `Ad` type](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201806/AdGroupAdService.Ad).

There's no default ad type per se, but I suppose you could call the [Expanded Text Ad](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201806/AdGroupAdService.ExpandedTextAd) the default one—it's the classic text ad on top of a SERP.

As for your specific question about the Product Ads, these are ads that are used in [Shopping Campaigns](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2454022). They are created automatically by Adwords based on the information in the advertiser's merchant center account.